# TFSBuild command from cmd.exe is failing with an error Visual studio 2017

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Trying to run TFSBuild /queue from command prompt. The command fails to recognize TFSBuild and fails with error as "'TFSBuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." in server where VS 2017 is installed. The same command works on server where VS2015 is installed.

Comment: Have you try to open your source code with Visual Studio 2017 and build it with VS 2017 to generate the new TFSBuild. Then run the command `TFSBuild /queue` from command prompt in the server where VS2017 is installed? It seems this file is generated by VS2015, not recognized by VS2017.

Comment: Yes. Opened source Code and connected to server tried to run the command TFSBuild /queue from command prompt and through MSBuild. Still the same error. Tried it with dev command prompt and that worked. But MSBuild exe command works only through normal cmd prompt.

Comment: What do you mean "run the command TFSBuild /queue from command prompt and through MSBuild"? How did you do that? Can you share some more detailed info or steps about what have you done? And if you use MSBuild from command prompt , you should convert the path to the location where MSBuild installed, for example, VS2017, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`.

Comment: I have a MSBuild command <Exec Command="TFSBuild start (ServerURL) (Project) (BuildDefinition) /queue" ContinueOnError="true"/> The same command executes well in build server where VS2015 is installed and fails in server where VS2017 is installed. On debugging a bit observed that, the same command when run from command prompt (not developer command prompt) in server where VS2015 is installed works. But the same fails in the server where VS2017 is installed. All the required environment variables and server configurations are same in both the servers.

Comment: how about switch path to the location where MSBuild installed, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` before you run command on the normal cmd prompt. It seems you have add a path of MSBuild.exe to the system environment variables, please the variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well adding

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
```

to path variables resolved the issue. TFSBuild.exe resides in the above path. Adding the above path to path variables, I am able to execute TFSBuild from normal command prompt.